# PHP: How do I find out if array has a string that has a string?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, while-loop

I need to make a loop that checks if an array ( $array ), contains a string ( 'thisisaverylongstring' ), that contains another string ( 'isavery' ).

How would I write this in valid PHP?

Comment: Did you tried `in_array()` and `array_search()` functions ?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? [Looping over an array](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)? [Finding a substring in a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)?

Comment: Is it an array of arrays or just an array of strings ?

Comment: If the second string you're searching for is always going to be a substring of the first string you're searching, why not only search for the first string?

Comment: Every value that contains `'thisisaverylongstring'` will contain `'isavery'`. So why don't you look for the short one only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stringToLookFor = 'isavery';
$inArray = FALSE; //does the string exist in the array?
foreach($array as $string)
{
    if(strpos($string, $strongToLookFor) !== FALSE)
    {
         $inArray = TRUE;
    }
}

if($inArray)
{
    echo 'String "' . $stringToLookFor . '" found in array';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is a simple as you say it is, you can use [stripos](https://www.php.net/stripos) (case insensitive string search):

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if (stripos($element, 'isavery') !== false) {
        echo 'Found it!';
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your actual requirement is but as from my understanding the following function could work

```
  function checkInArray($array, $val)
{
    if(in_array($val,$array))
    return true;    
}
function checkvalinarray($array2D, $val1, $val2)
{
foreach($array2D as $array1D)
{
    if(checkInArray($array1D,$val2))
    return true;    
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arrayData = array('This is a very long string',
                   'This is a short string',
                  );
$needle = 'very';

$matches = array_filter( $arrayData,
                         function($data) use ($needle) { 
                             return (stripos($data,$needle) !== FALSE); 
                         }
                       );
if (count($matches) > 0) {
    echo 'Match found';
}
var_dump($matches);
```